# Parsing Error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, mean-stack, angular-services

I am working on a MEAN STACK application and I am trying to create a `AngularJS` factory that makes use of `$http`. Below is the code of my `gMapService.js`.

**gMapService.js**

```
var myApp = myApp.factory("gMapService",['$http', function($http){
var urlBase = "https://mymapservice.com/api/function/json";
    return {
        function1: function (arg) {
            return{
                $http.get(urlBase, {
                    cache: true,
                    headers:{
                      "Content-Type":"application/json"
                    },
                    params:{
                        address:arg
                    }
                })
                .then(function (resp) { 
                    return resp.data; 
                });   
        }
    };   
}]);
```

I have used a similar code in the past and I never had an issue with it until now where my code editor is signaling this error in

> line 6: Parsing Error: Unexpected token .

Please tell me what i am doing wrong here. I am using `angular 1.5.8`

Comment: Which line no 6 ?

Comment: in `gMapService.js`

Comment: buddy,please copy your response and check in any json validation tool for json is correct or not

Comment: I tried that but my concern is that it doesn't make sense to me. i have used similar code in the past and it works. Please let me know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 4):

You have a misguided `}` character after the declaration of *function1*, just remove that character:

```
var myApp = myApp.factory("gMapService", ["$http", function($http) {
    var urlBase = "https://mymapservice.com/api/function/json";
    return {
        function1: function(arg) {
            return $http.get(urlBase, {
                cache: true,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                params: {
                    address: arg
                }
            })
                .then(function(resp) {
                    return resp.data;
                });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: thanks riyaj. I will give it a try later. keep you posted.